# HTML5 Multiplayer Browser Game

Tags: php, html, multiplayer

I am having difficulty with one part of my simple HTML5 game. I've decided to make it multiplayer. How do I go about making a change to the position of a div on my screen visible on the other users screen?

It's a two player game, with a simple move left and move right function to move divs. My first thought was to use sessions, but when I got to writing some code, I realised I knew nothing, so I headed over to [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) (couldn't find anything for my use), headed over to [Dave Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/) (nothing listed) and couldn't find anything of use on Google, no matter what search term I put in.

I know this is possible with modern browsers as I've seen it done in a lot of games online now, however I'm baffled as to how it's done.

Any answer with some links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sessions are a per-user thing. you cannot share data between multiple users using sessions unless you start using duplicate session IDs, which is VERY risky. You need a proper server-backend for this sort of thing, to share the data.

Comment: I suggest Node.js I think it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be interested in [this](http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2011/08/creating-realtime-multiplayer-games-using-node-js/) article. It is an example of making online multiplayer game with NodeJS. It reveals some concepts as well as gives the actual code.

Comment: As mentioned in @Charles380 comment. I was looking into this when he mentioned it, this looks like what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities within the simple ones:
1- refresh automatically the page of both users periodically - not very fancy
2- use ajax to query the server of a possible move from the other player

The option 2 would work well if it is a turn-by-turn game. In case of online game, I think you would need much more complex server technology like Node.js for instance.

Comment: For option 1, would I need to log each move the user makes into an SQL table? The game isn't turn based. I was hoping to have it in real time, so you can see the other player moving as and when they click the mouse button (obviously not right away).

Comment: So you will need to use Nodejs or something similar. It is pretty much harder to implement. If you know javascript it will be ok, if not, it may be painful.

Comment: I'm fairly competent with Javascript, so I'll give it a good shot. Thanks for the link to the article again.